# Cannot block external access to website, but allow internal users

Tags: php, .htaccess, security

We have a cpanel server that runs multiple websites.  There is one website we want to block external access for.  I have tried the following rules:

```
order deny,allow
deny from all
allow from 10.10.0.0/16
allow from 127.0.0.1
```

I have tried a variety of combinations for the allow rules, but none allow access from the internal network.  I always get the error

```
Forbidden

You don't have permission to access / on this server.
Additionally, a 403 Forbidden error was encountered while trying to use an 
ErrorDocument to handle the request."
```

Comment: Is your server located on your internal network.  If your route to these servers uses an external gateway, then the IP addresses you need to allow are the ones of the gateway and not 10.10.0.0.

Answer (score 0):

Hi and welcome to Stackoverflow!

I would suggest, as per the second example given at [this page](http://www.htaccess-guide.com/deny-visitors-by-ip-address/), that you try swapping the order of your allow and deny like so:\

```
order allow,deny
allow from 10.10.0.0/16
allow from 127.0.0.1
deny from all
```

While I am not able to test this, it would make sense for Apache to follow the first applicable rule. In this case, deny for all would always be followed as all clients fall under the filter of all. However, only a small subset of clients fall under the allow filters, and so I would expect it to stop testing upon allowing those clients.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion.  I have tried as you suggest without success.  I have read elsewhere that deny has to be first due to how rules are matched, but I am far from an expert on this topic - as can clearly be seen by not been able to allow access to my own network!

Comment: I wonder if maybe Apache does not like the subnet. What happens if you remove the /16? Also, can you access the webpage from this server? The easiest way to find out would be to attempt to wget a file from the site, if you have the ability to do so from the server. Furthermore, what do the Apache logs say?

Comment: Interesting development.  I can access the internal server externally if I allow the individual ip address I am using at the moment.  I don't know how to do the wget, so I will look that up now and report back

Comment: Even stranger.  If I had the external ip address for the computers that are on the internal network they are able to access the webserver.  I find this rather strange as they should be going direct to the server.  I will run some tracert and see what is going on.

Comment: Answer is an internal routing issue - the internal clients are approaching from the external facing ip address, hence all the internal ip address allows did not function.  Thank you very much for your help, saved me a few hours knowing that what I had started was correct.